# `$request->ajax()` does not detect ajax request when using Fetch API to pull data in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, fetch

In my `Laravel` app, I am using `Fetch API` to load data on scroll. Below is my `JS` code in blade file

```js
let route = '{{ route("load") }}' + '?q=' + encodeURI('{{ $para }}');
fetch(route)
.then(response => {
   if(!response.ok) {
       throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
   }
   return response.text();
})
.then(data => {                       
   console.log(data);                       
})
.catch((error) => {
   console.error('Error:', error);
})
```

And in my controller

```php
public function loadData( Request $request )
{
    if( $request->ajax() ) {

       return $request->query('q');

     }
     return 'Not Ajax!';
}
```

It always return 'Not Ajax!';

I am not sure why this is happening. It was not a problem with other libraries like `jQuery` or `Axios`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Request::ajax()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L238) checks for the existance of the `X-Requested-With` header.

Since you're using fetch, you have to manually add this header to the [options object](https://github.github.io/fetch/#options):

```
fetch(route, {
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  },
})
```

Axios, for example, uses this by default due to how the [bootstrap.js file is set up](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/js/bootstrap.js#L11). jQuery [adds it automatically](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js#L44) for every request but cross-domain requests.

Comment: Very nice and well explained . Thanks
I also stumbled to https://benjaminlistwon.com/blog/adding-more-robust-ajax-detection-in-laravel/, which cleared my doubt further.

Answer (score 0):

Please try  to use **request()->ajax()** function instead of **$request->ajax()**. I think the problem is you have imported the wrong Request at the top. It happens with me also because of Editor

Comment: Not working. I think $request is correct, because I can see `$request->query('q')` value if remove the ajax check.